# (Beginner) SQLAlchemy JOIN with SQLITE

Tags: python, sqlite, join, sqlalchemy

I am studying sqlalchemy and I cannot understand the reason for this error.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, MetaData, INTEGER, String, ForeignKey, ForeignKeyConstraint
from sqlalchemy.sql import Select

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')

with engine.connect() as conn:
    meta = MetaData(engine)

    cars = Table('Cars', meta,
                 Column('Id', INTEGER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
                 Column('Name', String, nullable=False),
                 Column('BrandId', INTEGER, ForeignKey('Brands.Id')))


    brands = Table('Brands', meta,
                  Column('Id', INTEGER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
                  Column('Name', String))

    meta.create_all()

    cars_values = [{'Name':'Escort', 'BrandId':1}]
    brands_values = [{'Id':1, 'Name': 'Ford'}]

    insert1 = brands.insert().values(brands_values)
    insert2 = cars.insert().values(cars_values)
    conn.execute(insert1)
    conn.execute(insert2)

    query = Select([cars]).join(brands, brands.c.Id == cars.c.BrandId)
    #query = 'select * from cars c JOIN brands b on b.id = c.brandid'
    result = conn.execute(query)

    print(result.fetchall())
```

When I run this way, I get an error

```
Select([cars]).join(brands, brands.c.Id == cars.c.BrandId)
```

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: <sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Join at 0x1e62654ed88; Join object on Select object(2087997204936) and Brands(2087997203848)>
```

But if you run raw sql the JOIN is accepted

```
'select * from cars c JOIN brands b on b.id = c.brandid'
```

```
[(1, 'Escort', 1, 1, 'Ford')]
```

Comment: Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
query = select(['*']).select_from(cars.join(brands, brands.c.Id == cars.c.BrandId))
# print(query)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
# SELECT * FROM "Cars" JOIN "Brands" ON "Brands"."Id" = "Cars"."BrandId"
```

see [Using Joins](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html#using-joins)

Comment: Since `Cars.BrandId` is defined as a `ForeignKey` the second argument to `join` is redundant. You can just use `query = select(['*']).select_from(cars.join(brands))`

Answer (score 0):

This is another way

from sqlalchemy import text

query   = text("select c.Id, c.Name,c.BrandId, b.Id, b.Name from Cars c left join
Brands b on b.Id = b.Id ")

result  = engine.execute(query)